# useCallback memoize the function called inside it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a case where i wanted to call a normal function inside useCallback hook.

```
myCallback = useCallback(() => {
    if (isTrue && isOver) {
        ToggleState();
    }
}, [isTrue, isOver]);

const ToggleState = () => {
    setOver(!isOver);
    //... some other updates too
};

useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('click', myCallback);
        return () => document.removeEventListener('click', myCallback);
    }, [myCallback]);
```

Will `ToggleState` also get memoized here?
Do we need to add it into the dependency array?

Answer (score 1):

No it will not get memoized.

Also you will probably have some incorrect state values if you do not include `Toggle` in the dependency array. `myCallback` will always be called with the first version of `Toggle` and that is not what you expect.

Now you would want to put `Toggle` in your dependency array, but notice `Toggle` is also created afresh in every render. Then either you wrap it in `useCallback` too or you define `Toggle` completely inside your `useCallback` (myCallback).

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-sky-y19crb?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response @Tushar Shahi. I got it will memoize only the useCallback function. I have updated my question with full scenario.

Comment: As ToggleState won't get memoized with values. It's not needed in the dependency array right!